# Export multiple Vue components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am creating a node_module with Vue SFC components for consumption of different projects.

So on my module's index.js (main entry point), I have this:

```
import component1 from './src/input-box1.vue'
import component2 from './src/input-box2.vue'

export default component1
```

Above works well for `component1` but I don't know how to export `component2`.

I tried doing this:

```
export { component1 }
export { component2 }
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Unknown custom element: <component1> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option
```

Import is like this:

```
import component1 from 'sample-vue-components'
```

Any ideas??

Comment: `export default { component1, component2, ... }` or  `export component1; export component2; ..`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't put `{}` it is the default export that will be imported.
Try modifying your export/import like:

in your sample-vue-components.vue:

```
import component1 from './src/input-box1.vue'
import component2 from './src/input-box2.vue'

export { component1, component2 };
```

Then import them like:

```
import { component1, component2 } from 'sample-vue-components'
```